# duplicate kubernetes namespace with the content

Tags: testing, kubernetes, namespaces

How can I duplicate a namespace with all content with a new name in the same kubernetes cluster?

e.g. Duplicate default to my-namespace which will have the same content.

I'm interested just by services and deployments, so
when I try with method with kubectl get all and with api-resources i have error with services IP like :

```
Error from server (Invalid): Service "my-service" is invalid: spec.clusterIP: Invalid value: "10.108.14.29": provided IP is already allocated
```

Comment: In the workflows I'm used to, you'd check out the source control repository holding the Kubernetes YAML files again if you needed to, then run `kubectl apply` or `helm install` with a different `--namespace` argument.  That means having all of the original YAML available and not using imperative-type Kubernetes commands, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @coderanger mentioned in his answer, there is no straight way to make a copy of origin k8s resources to the separate namespace.

As was proposed, when you invoke `kubectl get all` command, k8s looks through resources catalog bounded to ***all*** category. Therefore, if you didn't add this category for each custom [*CRD*](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-kubernetes-api/custom-resources/custom-resource-definitions/#create-a-customresourcedefinition) object, throughout specific [API group](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/#api-groups), you might probably miss some relevant k8s resources in the command output.

Furthermore, if you desire to export all k8s resources from the particular namespace, besides user [*workloads*](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/#kubernetes-objects), I would recommend exploring [API resources](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#resource-types), filtering out only namespace scoped objects, and then apply bash processing to generate manifest files across each resource group:

```
kubectl api-resources --namespaced=true| awk '{print $1}'| sed '1d'| while read -r line; do echo "$(kubectl get $line -n namespace -o yaml > $line.yaml)"; done
```

You can also consider using [Helm](https://helm.sh/) (as @David Maze pointed out in the comment), in order to manage user workloads through Helm [*Charts*](https://helm.sh/docs/developing_charts/#charts), as a more flexible and structured way to describe k8s native resources.

Comment: When i try with method with kubectl get all and with api-resources i have error with services IP like :

Error from server (Invalid): Service "my-service" is invalid: spec.clusterIP: Invalid value: "10.108.14.29": provided IP is already allocated

Comment: You can supply `--export` flag to `kubectl get` command: `kubectl get all -n namespace -o yaml --export` , excluding cluster related data from origin `yaml` print out.

Comment: --export is deprecated and it will be removed in the next version

Answer (score 3):

There is no specific way to do this. You could probably get close with something like `kubectl get all -n sourcens -o yaml | sed -e 's/namespace: sourcens/namespace:  destns/' | kubectl apply -f -` but `get all` is always a bit wonky and this could easily miss weird edge cases.

Answer (score 3):

You can backup your namespace using **Velero** and then you can restore it to another namespace or cluster!